# Are there any hidden words in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, sentence-patterns

Children growing up in Costa Rica are surrounded by some of the most beautiful and diverse landscapes in the world........................................................................................................................

Am I right ?......................
...........................................................................................................
Children "are" growing up in Costa Rica"which they" are surrounded by some of the most beautiful and diverse landscapes in the world.
.................................................................................................
Are "are" and "which they" hidden in the above sentence?

Comment: [reduced relative clauses](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107).... some call it, whiz deletion, I think is what you are asking about. I *think* because the question as it looks, is not very clear.

Comment: If you want to start a new line, press the spacebar twice and then "enter" tab. Please get rid of those dotted lines.

Comment: Related: [“I hate Jill singing those songs.” = “I hate Jill when she is singing those songs.”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/434684/i-hate-jill-singing-those-songs-i-hate-jill-when-she-is-singing-those-song) and [Shakespearean relative clause: “I have a brother is condemned to die”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427995/shakespearean-relative-clause-i-have-a-brother-is-condemned-to-die)

Comment: The word "are" is not missing or hidden, you would simply reposition it. The "which they" would be completely out of place, unless you say "where they..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no ellipsis in your example. "Children growing up in Costa Rica" could be replace by "childen who grow up/are growing up in Costa Rica" without changing the sense, but that would be a different construction. "Which they" is entirely impossible to put into your sentence, though you could say "[Some] children grow up in Costa Rica, where they are surrounded...". Again, this is a different construction, and not quite the same meaning.

The main verb is "are surrounded"; the subject is the entire phrase before that.