# Is this natural? "There's somebody wants to see you."

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I have learned the following sentence is grammatically correct because it is possible to omit the nominative relative pronoun in a sentence like "there is ...". I'm not sure if it is natural or not in real, however. I would like to ask three questions about it.

***There's somebody wants to see you.***

Q1. Is the sentence natural? Why?

Q2. Does the inclusion of the relative "who" make a difference in nuance? If so, what is the difference?

Q3. Is it possible to use "there is" instead of the contraction form, "there's" in the sentence? Why?

Comment: You could either say "somebody wants to see you" or "there is/there's (no difference) somebody who wants to see you". The option you provided is not correct or idiomatic (in any dialect I've heard)

Comment: Consensus seems to be that it's mainly dialectal or informal https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst199349_There-s-somebody--who--wants-you-on-the-phone-.aspx https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/theres-somebody-wants-to-see-you.123983/ I can find similar examples from [London c. 1950s](https://www.hippostcard.com/listing/theres-somebody-wants-you-artist-donald-mcgill/29590369) and [New York State c. 1900](http://www.eyewitnesstohistory.com/hobo.htm). I can't find anything authoritative though.

Comment: It's not correct and yet is still acceptable in New York. It implies you will want to meet. Were the gatekeeper less charmed by that *somebody*, you'd hear *Guy to see ya. You don't have time, do ya?*

Comment: @Esther: Where are you based? It's perfectly natural in relaxed *British* conversational contexts to omit the relativiser *(**who** or **that**)* in the cited context. And I'm far from convinced any professional *linguists* would say that it's "ungrammatical" to do so, even if some pedantic grammarians might think there's something wrong with it. So far as I'm concerned, the only grammatical "rule" involved here is the one saying [that] such relativisers (especially, ***that***) are ***always*** "optional, discardable".

Comment: @FumbleFingers hmm, maybe I was overly harsh. It sounds very wrong to me, but I can't say I've never heard it or can't imagine someone saying it.

Comment: I have heard "There's someone what wants to see you" in such as _Peaky Blinders_...a street usage which  is usually conveyed in a menacing tone.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ Yes, and that use of what is common in Dickens. it's basically Cockney.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think there's quite a few UK varieties where you could *always* omit the subject. However, for many there's a cline of acceptability according to other factors. There's something about the existential construction that makes OP's example fine in my variety. But, in contrast, *I met a woman broke her leg* doesn't work in my variety at all.

Comment: As many have said, it has a missing "who". But that missing "who" could equally be a missing "that".

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: You're quite right. I overstated my case - I absolutely agree your *woman broke her leg* example isn't idiomatic for most people, but I wouldn't know how to formally identify those contexts where it seems more "necessary" to include the relativiser. Note that several written instances of the sequence [*{do} **you know anyone needs** {something I want to sell}*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+know+anyone+needs%22)  match this context. But that's a pretty "dialectal, uneducated" usage, for sure.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Intuitively, it seems like it’s more acceptable when the relative clause modifies one of the compound determiners: *any/some/no* + *one/body/thing/place/where*.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: Also *less* acceptable (totally unacceptable?) where the relative clause modifies the *subject* of an utterance. *A guy needed a light took my matches* sounds pretty dire to me, but *I gave my matches to a guy needed a light* doesn't sound too bad (it *looks* worse than it sounds, though! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I think you’re right. And there’s definitely a cline of acceptability there.

Comment: Another variation that I've seen (not heard) but don't know enough about to turn into an answer: _There's somebody **as** wants to see you._

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's these comments here I was angling at :)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore: Looking again at your example here (many years later), I think the word ***looking*** is crucial. In a *conversational* context, I wouldn't notice anything remotely unusual about discarding the [***optional***, imho] relativiser ***who*** in *I met a woman broke her leg*. It's only in the more formal ***written*** context that I'd normally notice any "syntactic looseness" there.

Answer (score 9):

This isn’t correct in written English and I believe it’d be considered a mistake here on the West Coast of the United States, although it shouldn’t be a big deal to misspeak one word in a sentence, occasionally.  I’m used to filling in a missing word due to background noise or a poor telephone connection.

The following all sound more natural to me:

- There’s somebody here to see you
- There’s somebody here who wants to see you
- There’s somebody here that wants to see you

*There is* would also be possible, but to my ear, makes the register of the sentence clash. It starts out too formally to get that casual about the relative pronoun later on.

I believe it’s more common in some other dialects, but I’ll let people from those places speak to that..

Comment: Another possibility is just "Somebody wants to see you". Grammatically, the most straightforward. May need a verbal prefix like "Er" or a visual gesture, to avoid seeming abrupt.

Comment: @nigel222 Come to think of it, “Nigel, somebody’s here to see you!” would work well too, or “Somebody here to see you!” in casual speech.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't look as though anyone has addressed your third question yet, so I'll give it a shot.

Omitting the relative pronoun "who" would be unusual in formal speech. (As you can see from other answers and comments, many people consider it incorrect.) Therefore, this sentence is likely to be interpreted as casual / slang / colloquial. For that reason, the contracted form "there's" works well here. However, writing out "there is" would certainly be grammatical and might even be useful in some contexts (for example, if you wanted to place stress on "is").

Comment: Exactly. It's not what you'd want in the minutes of the meeting. But nobody reads minutes anyway.

Answer (score 5):

According to this reference "who" should not be omitted in this sentence.

> ([PristineWord](https://www.pristineword.com/omit-pronoun-that-who-which/)) Look at this sentence.
>
> - **Correct** The waiter who served us yesterday was rude.
>
> The subject of the relative clause is **who** (the waiter), so we cannot leave out the relative pronoun. However, we can omit it in another way (see step 2).
>
> - **incorrect** The waiter served us yesterday was rude.
>
> **2** **When the relative pronoun is the subject, we can omit that, who, or which in two basic ways**:
>
> > If **that, who**, or **which** is followed by the verb "be" (in any form), both elements can be omitted.
>
> - **Correct**   The keys that are on the table are mine.
> - **Correct** The keys on the table are mine.
>
> > If that, who, or which is followed by a verb, both elements (pronoun and verb) can be changed into "-ing" form of the verb.
>
> - **Correct**    People who follow healthy diets tend to live longer.
> - **Correct**    People following healthy diets tend to live longer.

You could say this.

- There is somebody wanting to see you.

In formal writing, always use "there is".

Comment: That looks like a resource for English learners, which reduce everything to "standard English" and never cover dialectical forms (which the example seems to be, judging from the comments).

Comment: @Laurel I conceive it rather as aimed at users of  English—I am myself one still in need to resort to rules and compendiums of usage—, not desirous to allow their speech to be identified  to any particular dialect nor to a strictly informal type of English, but instead, concerned with preserving a standard not likely to deviate much from what is  generally accepted.

Comment: @Lambie 1/  Yes, "in need of resorting to" :  idiomatic now . 2/ No, "not willing to" (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+willing+to+allow&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20willing%20to%20allow%3B%2Cc0) 3/ Yes, "with" is idiomatic, "to" is not, apparently. 4/ No, I mean "preserve", not "follow" (people concerned with preserving a standard for themselves and not spreading any standards). Thank you very much for your time and what is pertinent in your editing.

Comment: "There is somebody wanting to see you" is correct in Indian English, but sounds very strange to British English speakers (and I've never heard that form in American English either).

Comment: @JackAidley It seems that "someone wanting to see you" is quite acceptable; see for yourself : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22someone%20wanting%20to%20see%20you%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en . Yet, if you replaced "somebody" by "someone" the construction would not be valid any more. That seems rather strange to me. What do you think?

Comment: "There is somebody **waiting** to see you" is perfectly natural BrE, but not so much "There is somebody **wanting** to see you". It's just that the continuous participle is more typically noticed as "Indian English" with verbs reflecting mental states (such as *I'm loving this song!* instead of "mainstream" *I love this song!*).

Comment: I'd agree with the pronouncement: '**incorrect**: _The waiter served us yesterday was rude._ However, _There's somebody wants to see you_ sounds like the conversational deletion Lee Van Cleef or Edward G. Robinson would use. I'd only use it in mimicry, though I expect there are areas of the US where it would not trigger the 'Ham!' impression I doubtless usually invoke. I'd not recommend its use in any formal communication. // I feel the preposing of existential 'There's' makes the difference here; 'There is' perhaps mixes registers incongruously.

Answer (score 4):

In British English, we would normally include the 'who', as in:

> There's somebody **who** wants to see you

You would still be easily understood if it were omitted. I think it would depend on the individual (British) listener whether it made the sentence sound 'odd' to them.  To my ear *"There's somebody wants to see you"* would sound American.

Comment: And to an American ear like mine, "There's somebody wants to see you" would sound like something out of a TV show set in rural England.

Comment: @Spencer - To my N BrE [metropolitan] ear it sounds absolutely fine as colloquial speech. Sure, there's a missing word, but it's still a perfectly natural omission.

Answer (score 1):

> - *There's somebody wants to see you.*

is perfectly normal spoken English. One might add /t/ at the end of *somebody* to show a deleted *that*, or one might use an extra vowel there to show a deleted *who*. Or one might make an inaudible tongue gesture in either direction, and feel satisfied they'd pronounced the requisite pronoun.

Of course, English writing doesn't allow us the benefit of merely transcribing the language as it's spoken. Unless we dare the slings and arrows of outrageous peeving, we must pretend that we talk different. How you want to pretend is up to you.

Comment: Right-o. And for me, there are basically two grammar codes, one spoken and another written.

Comment: Shouldn't we, rather than talk of naturally spoken English, refer to slurred speech, which, if common enough in certain contexts  but can't still be qualified as natural? Hurried speech, for instance, is never what one would call quite natural.

Comment: One might add--to deter peevers who think we should speak English like people did in Shakespeare's day--that this used to be the most frequent way of reducing relative clauses altogether (to omit the *that/which/who* when it was the subject) in Shakespeare's day. And he did it all the time. In contrast, omitting the relative word when it represented a missing object, as is normal nowadays, was relatively rare. [[See here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427995/shakespearean-relative-clause-i-have-a-brother-is-condemned-to-die/428034#428034), for example.]

Comment: @LPH No, we shouldn't speak of slurred speech, unless we're speaking of the way drunk people talk. That's real slurring. Contracting meaningless words like auxiliaries is just normal speech. It's just that it doesn't get represented in printed materials, which is due to printers and editors, not to any supposed "natural" character. It's the way it's done because it's the way it's done, and thats it.

Comment: I am not speaking about "clean" omissions, which are well established in informal speech and writing, and "slurred" is as you mention, not exact, I can see that now. However, hurried speech is more like what you are describing, and it seems this type of elocution should not  be determining, but merely tolerated occasionally.

Comment: There is no standard speed for speech. Everybody has their own set of rates, and they use them differently in different contexts. We all know people that talk slow and we all know people that talk fast. It's no use pretending there is a proper form of speech that emerges at one velocity and no faster or slower.

Comment: "There's somebody wants to see you is perfectly normal spoken English". Which "spoken English" are we talking about? Where? I have absolutely never heard this in my entire existence.

Comment: I have also never heard any native English say "there's somebody wants to see you". People say "Somebody wants to see you" or "There's somebody here to see you". It's the kind of mistake I'd expect from a semi-fluent non-native speaker.

Comment: "is perfectly normal spoken English" no it's not.

Comment: *Which "spoken English" are we talking about?* This once again is the key point. Just because someone in California has never heard it doesn't mean that a Brit wouldn't have met it a hundred times.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not an English major or teacher of any kind, but it *was* my strongest subject, and the statement you're asking about sounds absolutely wrong. That doesn't mean it's grammatically incorrect, but I would be shocked if it wasn't. The "*there's*" should be dropped from the statement altogether as it's unnecessary, gratuitous, and, as I mentioned, sounds 100% grammatically incorrect.

Then again, we added "*ain't*" as a contraction to the dictionary, sooo... what do I know? LOL I think Pink Floyd said it best...

> *"We don't need no education!"*